# Wife's data restored on my phone

Tags: itunes, backup, restore

I have an new computer, and installed iTunes.  When I plugged in my iPhone, it asked if I wanted to restore my phone, or start as a new phone.  I said restore, but it restored my wife's phone data, and wiped out my email on 3 accounts.  How do I go back

Comment: Do you both use separate accounts on your Mac?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a backup of your iPhone on iCloud or another computer, you can restore from there. If you don't, you'll have to reset and setup as new.